# tool tip ie 7 issues

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I have about 50-100 links and made a tool tip for it.It is a simple tool tip but the real problem is ie7. The tooltip is working fine and I think there is some problem in the code.here is the code.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[id$='_down']").hover(function(){
      $(this).parent().next().toggle()
  });
});
  });
```

I am using id's for the div and you can have look at [this link](http://jsbin.com/ifizat/1/edit) and you will get an idea.

Comment: Why do you have two document.ready functions?

Comment: I am sorry my mistake but still that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@fahad.kazi IE always causes trouble, when it comes to JS and some CSS properties.

However, whenever I needed to display a tooltip in IE, I have used **title** attribute in almost all of my assignments, which looks somewhat like a tooltip.

```
<a href="" title="hello world">Hello World</a>
```

The sample code of it is shown below. For an example, you refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Pa3a7/).